# Update nagios from 3.3 to 3.5 on a fedora server

Tags: installation, nagios, fedora

I am currently using a Fedora 15 server and I have Nagios 3.3.1 installed already. I want to update it to 3.5.0. How can I do that?

Tried to do fresh installation using the steps of http://www.linux4beginners.info/?q=node/nagiosfedora. But it gives me an error when I `make install`

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `nagios': No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [install-basic] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/nagios/base'
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/nagios/base'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

How can I update Nagios or fix the above problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this isn't the answer you want to hear, but you should upgrade the underlying OS as a matter of urgency; Nagios will then follow suit.

Fedora 15 is end-of-life, isn't supported any more, and hasn't been for the best part of a year.  F16 is also now end-of-life and unsupported.

F17 is currently still supported, comes with Nagios 3.4.4, and isn't disliked by quite as many people as F18 (which has been controversial in the community).  You can also upgrade from F15 directly to F17 (Fedora only supports a jump of two versions in a single upgrade).  If you decide to go cutting-edge, F18 also comes with Nagios 3.4.4.

You don't say why you specifically need 3.5.0; if you have a good reason, then my advice isn't helpful.  But if you're just wanting to get your Nagios up-to-patch, then the underlying problem is that you've let your distro get out-of-patch, and the applications that comes with have aged at the same time.  Get your distro up-to-patch, and your applications will come with it.

Comment: @keith, FYI regarding your edit, [Nagios is actually an acronym](http://www.nagios.org/about/history), I believe it's a valid edit though, as the developers themselves call it 'Nagios'.

Answer (score 0):

either you did miss 'make all' to compile the binaries such as 'nagios' or this did generate an error and did not create any of those. verify the output of 'make all' - to start fresh, hit 'make clean' once before.